# App apk and aab file still large after generation

Tags: android, database, sqlite, apk, android-room

My app's apk and aab file are both 61 and 63 mb respectively. This is due to the prepackaged database it contains. Is there anyway to further reduce the app size?

I've used shrinkResources, minifyEnabled and proguard but they all do little since the size is mainly due to the database.

Comment: Do you mean the AAB file or the actually installed app which is extracted from the AAB?

Android app bundle files won't be smaller than universal APKs. The extracted APK which is generated for the end user will be smaller.

Comment: The extracted apk and the aab file are virtually the same size.

Answer (score 0):

1. use less local Images.
2. Remove All Unused Methods, Classes, Fields, Attributes, and Resources.
3. Enable Resource Shrinking

```
    buildTypes {
       release {
        shrinkResources true
           minifyEnabled true
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: I've already done all these as stated in the post